# How would I store a value into read for Scheme? Or is that not even possible?

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, cdr

```
(define (getFirstFew lst)
  (cond
  ((= (read) 0) '()) ;returns nothing
  (else(cons (car lst)(getFirstFew (cdr lst)(- (read) 1))))))
```

That is my code above. So i'm trying to write a procedure that will get the first x elements (user gets to choose what x gets to be) from a list. For example,  input 4 with (getFirstFew '(1 6 2 4 5)) will result in '(1 6 2 4).

My current problem with this is that with using read two times, it gets called twice and then breaks the program. Is there a way for me to store whatever the user inputs into a variable and then use that variable throughout the program? Or is there another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you have to perform the `read` only *once*, and store the value for future reference. Normally we'd use a [`let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html) for this, but given that we also have to iterate over the list and decrement `x` on each iteration, a [named `let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29) will be more appropriate. Try this:

```
(define (getFirstFew lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (x (read)))
    (if (= x 0)
        '()
        (cons (car lst)
              (loop (cdr lst) (- x 1))))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(getFirstFew '(1 6 2 4 5))
> 4
=> '(1 6 2 4)
```

Comment: Note that having that `read` inside a function `getFirstFew` is highly misleading and should be considered bad code style IMO. A function `take N lst` or `getFirst N lst` would be a better choice.